# The tag “confusing” should be deleted

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleaning

I found that on Ell Stack Exchange, there is a tag called [confusing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/confusing) and I found that this tag was used by 1 question. That question actually asked about the prepositions after the word “confusing”.

(SEE HERE: ["confusing for tourists" vs "confusing to the user"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/345747/confusing-for-tourists-vs-confusing-to-the-user))

I don’t think that we need that tag, and I think that the tag [prepositions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prepositions) and [confusable](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/confusable) is enough for that question.

Answer (score 5):

I removed the tag [confusing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/confusing) (which means it will soon be removed from the system entirely) but did not add [confusable](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/confusable), which I've never heard used for words that are not similar in either spelling or pronunciation; does it really serve a purpose not already covered by [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference)?

Comment: Confusable isn't useful for this question regardless. "Confusing " was added because they're asking about the word "confusing" not because the question is about something confusing.

Comment: Is this OP old enough to contribute on SE?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Escalated for review, but in the future you should raise a flag instead of a comment.